# Remove one element at index from the list inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to remove one element at index from the list `items` inside an array of objects using react.

For now, I do not know which method to use.

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
  {
    username: "Peter",
    items: [
      { name: "Bananas ", quantity: 10 },
      { name: "Strawberry ", quantity: 20 },
      { name: "Milk ", quantity: 6 },
    ],
  },
  {
    username: "William",
    items: [
      { name: "Brocolis ", quantity: 3 },
      { name: "Carottes ", quantity: 10 },
      { name: "Honey ", quantity: 2 },
    ],
  },
]);

// Remove element from list item (Pseudo Code)
function removeItem(index: number) {
  const initialState = [...users]
  initialState[userIndex].items.splice(itemIndex, 1)
  setUsers(initialState)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand, which element do you want to remove exactly ?

Comment: I want to remove any `item` in a user's `items` list by specifying its index.

Comment: @Olivier.C of which user? check my answer too

Comment: Let's say I want to delete an item from any user's list : `items`

Comment: @Olivier.C you should check my answer I think it covers your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove item with index: `itemIndex` from user with index `userIndex` user.

```
function removeItem(userIndex, itemIndex) {
    return users.map((x, i) => {
        if (i === userIndex) return {
            ...x,
            items: x.items.filter((y, j) => j !== itemIndex)
        }
        return x;
    })
}
```

You have to do it in immutable way since it comes from state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` for that

```
function removeItem(index: number) {
  setUsers(users.filter((user, userIndex) => userIndex !== index))
}
```

You can read more about `Array.prototype.filter` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)